# initialize mysql in host and access in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am creating very simple database like

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS example"
```

and I want to access it in the doker container like

```
"mysql://root@localhost/example"
```

both host and conteiner is ubuntu machine
I suppose answer is very simple but I got lost - Thanks !

Comment: Are you looking for the mechanisms described in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)  (More complicated on native Linux.)  Can you run the database in a container, alongside the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With docker, all the stuff can be accessible with localhost. But you need to expose the service to a local port.

So with `-p 80:80` in your run command, you will be able to expose the port 80 on your container, to your local port 80.

[Docker run doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks! so later I should access mysql like this "mysql://root@80/example"  ?

Comment: Don't forget the `localhost` and your password but it should work

"mysql://root:pwd@localhost:80/example"